# Is there a way to load an image in parallel with css load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I wanted to prioritize loading of the logo of our website. I've found preload or prefetching images but this just loads the image after css has been loaded and evaluated. How could I force the image to load in parallel with the css assets so that on first page paint, the image immediately shows?

Comment: Why does the image need to be loaded *before* the CSS is loaded? Why can the CSS not be loaded first?

Comment: Because by default, css is loaded and evaluated then renders the page. While the page is rendering, browser starts requesting the image. This delays the rendering and preview of that image which is the logo.

My goal is to show the logo immediately on first paint or the first preview of the page. So to do it, I need to request the image in parallel with the css so it finishes even before css is completed. So, if the css is finally loaded and evaluated, once the page renders, image is already ready to preview.

Comment: The parallel problem is solved with HTTP/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

1. Use an SVG version of your logo right in your html.
2. Use a Base64 encoded version of your logo if the size is small enough.

Comment: This could be a good solution. Although, I know it is off topic with this group but I'm worried that this might affect SEO. Any resource to confirm that it won't?

Comment: I'm not an expert on SEO, but I don't see any reason why it would. I would look into using appropriate `title` attributes for SVGs and imgs. Both of these are common techniques, and I don't think that any search engines consider image content (yet), only the titles and related attributes.

Comment: I've upvoted the answer since this is a good option but won't mark it as answer yet because of my concern with SEO. Would mark it as the right answer once this is confirmed.

Comment: @Bee It's a perfectly acceptable method for images by Google and Google outlines how to do it on their own web dev pages.

Comment: Based from what I've understood, this solution improves SEO becuase of the improvement on page load but affects indexing since it no longer has a name or url.

Comment: @Bee The URI doesn't matter and you still have alt for the image tag or SVG.

Comment: @Bee That's what I read, too. Not sure if you care about your logo being indexed or not, but you could always add a non-preloaded version of the image further down on the page that can be indexed.

Comment: @Bee if this answer answers your original question, it would be great if you accepted it as answered. That way other people with the same question can find it.